# What is the use of the 'protected' keyword inside a union?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I checked that the `protected` access specifier can be used inside `class`, `struct` as well as `union`. I know that the `protected` access specifier means that members will be private, but visible to derived class. I am not able to think of a reasonable use case where the `protected` keyword inside a union would be useful, because a union can't be part of an inheritance hierarchy. Since in a union `private` and `protected` would make no difference, why allow `protected` inside unions too?

Answer (score 15):

I'd say the real question is the opposite, why disallow it? Yes, it's synonymous to `private` in this case, but would it really be worth the (albeit minor) complication of the language and compiler implementation? It doesn't hurt in any way, either.